# How to set connection id in SignalR client?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, signalr

I need to set connection id before hubConnection.start();
I look here https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client and what i found:
connection.id - Gets or sets the client id for the current connection.
Tried this. No working. Here is the client code:

```
let hubUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/chat';
let hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(hubUrl)
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();
hubConnection.id = "12345";
hubConnection.on("Send", function (data) {
    let elem = document.createElement("p");
    elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
    let firstElem = document.getElementById("chatroom").firstChild;
    document.getElementById("chatroom").insertBefore(elem, firstElem);

});

document.getElementById("sendBtn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    let message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    hubConnection.invoke("Send", message);
});

hubConnection.start();
```

hubConnection.id = "12345"; this do not change real connection id.
And maybe you are know some other way how to write client-side connection?

Comment: Why do you need to set the connection ID? Why can't you just use what the system assigns?

Comment: i want to connection.id == ApplicationUser.Id in identityFramework

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What if the same user logs in from multiple tabs/windows/browsers at the same time? That's just going to be a nightmare to maintain. Instead, associate the connection with a specific user on the server side.

Comment: What if the same user logs in from multiple tabs/windows/browsers?
id will be the same everywhere. its just another value nothing more.... oO

Comment: A connection ID is supposed to be a unique value to individually identify a single connection. If you start having multiple connections with the same ID, things will break. You'll need to associate connections with specific users a different way.

Comment: @enkshlete You can not set connection Ids yourself, you are looking at it wrongly. Share with me your use case and I might point you in the right direction.

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil What about in the following use case: UI client subscribes to signalR hub on API, API makes call to 3rd party service provider end-point where connectionId is part of the payload, 3rd party SP does something then hits my API callback end-point with connectionId part of payload along with state of action performed, API callback  performs await _hubContext.Clients.Client(request.connectionId).SendAsync("MethodName", request.ActionStatus); but during 3rd party service action, client reconnected to API hub and has new connectionId?

Answer (score 1):

The connectionId can't be manually created or manipulated at all and it is created during negotiation request with the server.
 You can read [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb5225e2-16d7-495b-9525-74f933da789a/how-to-manually-set-the-connection-id?forum=aspsignalr) that you can implement your own `IConnectionIdFactory` but it is not recommended to do that.
 Maximum what you can do is get the `connectionId` and use it for mapping users and groups and other logic inside your hub.